# Archivo xlsx corrupto cuando subo por FTP Java

Tags: java, excel, ftp

Estoy tratando de subir un archivo por FTP, el archivo excel al parecer lo está copiando correctamente, pero al abrirlo me dice que está corrupto.

Alguna idea??

```
public static void enviarArchivoFTP(String localFile, String hostFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    //fis = new FileInputStream(localFile);
    BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localFile));
    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    if(ftp.storeFile(hostFile,buffIn))
        System.out.println("Envio correcto");
    else
        System.out.println("Error Envio");
    //fis.close();
    buffIn.close();
}
```

Comment: Hola @Eragonz91. Por favor, en lugar de editar tu pregunta y colocar "Resuelto <descripción de la solución>" publiques una respuesta y allí brindes detalles de cómo atendiste esta situación.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza la respuesta la pongo como comentario? o donde pongo la respuesta??

Comment: Ponla como una nueva respuesta, no como comentario.

Comment: Conviene que marques tu respuesta como aceptada. Si alguien tiene dudas parecidas y no hace lectura rigurosa puede ignorar las respuestas no aceptadas

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto el codigo posteado, lo que estaba mal es que el usuario no tenia permiso de escritura, probé intentando copiar un archivo en la carpeta y no podia. Probando con otro ftp que si tenia permiso me funciono bien.